# clickhouse MaterializedView getting error after running query on it

Tags: clickhouse

i created MaterializedView  with target table
after data is inserting to the view , i am trying to query the view but the query stop clickhouse-server after 1 second with error :
Exception on client:
Code: 32. DB::Exception: Attempt to read after eof: while receiving packet from localhost:9000, 127.0.0.1
the aggregation that  causing problem are
first_url SimpleAggregateFunction(any, String),
last_url SimpleAggregateFunction(anyLast, String),

why is that?

Comment: could you provide the sql-scripts? what is a source of origin data (Kafka, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it's a bug in CH.
CH version?

You should create a bug report and provide a table DDL, a full error message from CH logs, and data sample / reproducible example/ CH version.

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues

Answer (score 0):

i success fix it i used:
AggregateFunction(any, String),

and in the mv anyState:

what is the difference any vs anystat?

Comment: you did not fix. You used completely another functionality.

Comment: BTW, about any/anyLast you actually need argMaxState, argMinState